# Are electronic tire pressure gauges sensitive to temperature?

Tags: tires, tire-pressure

Recently, I purchased a quality made German mechanical dial-type tire pressure gauge. This was the only I could find with a quality certificate. The cheap Chinese mass-produced electronic tire pressure gauges typically lack such a quality certificate and can report incorrect readings that are repeatable but off by the same amount every time. The gauge I bought is the same that car magazines in my country use for calibration purposes.

This made me wonder whether an electronic tire pressure gauge can report different readings at different temperatures. What I mean by this is that the tire pressure gauge itself is stored in the car, and can have any temperature between -20 degrees Celsius and +30 degrees Celsius. What I don't mean is the normal variation of tire pressure between temperatures that is a real effect.

So, does temperature affect the accuracy of an electronic tire pressure gauge? I'm fairly certain the mechanical gauge won't be affected by temperature.

My Google skills weren't enough to find any definitive answer, but I assume a modern TPMS uses electronic sensors that work at different temperatures. But then again, TPMS only warns about severe underpressure, so it is not a precision instrument that has to be accurate.

Comment: "TPMS only warns about severe underpressure, so it is not a precision instrument that has to be accurate." Mine actually shows tire pressure for each wheel, and I have checked the readings with an accurate manual gauge and all 4 sensors are spot on.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice update, @Moab! Have you tested the same in different temperatures?

Comment: No I have not unfortunately.